# Cómo puedo volver el siguiente código de querySelector a querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript

En el siguiente código estoy ejecutando una función que solo afecta al primer **canvas** que está dentro de mi **body** con el **ID** **print**, lo que quisiera es asignar la misma función a todos los **canvas** que ya están dentro de mi **DOM** y a los que yo quiera agregar con **javascript**

```js
var wrapper = document.getElementById('print');
var canvas = wrapper.querySelector('canvas');
var signaturePad = new SignaturePad(canvas, {
  backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 255, 255)'
});

function resizeCanvas() {
  var ratio = Math.max(window.devicePixelRatio || 1, 1);

  // This part causes the canvas to be cleared
  canvas.width = (canvas.offsetWidth * ratio) / 2.5;
  canvas.height = (canvas.offsetHeight * ratio) / 3;
  canvas.getContext('2d').scale((ratio, ratio) / 2);

  signaturePad.clear();
}

window.onresize = resizeCanvas;
resizeCanvas();
```

Comment: si haces esto no funciona? var canvas = wrapper.querySelectorAll('canvas'); Despues tenes que iterar el resultado porque obtendrias un array con los elementos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para hacerlo con [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll) lo único que tienes que hacer es un bucle dentro de la función, para en lugar de aplicar los cambios al `canvas` seleccionado, lo hago a todos los `canvas` de la lista:

```
var canvas = document.querySelectorAll('canvas');
var signaturePad = new SignaturePad(canvas, {
  backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 255, 255)'
});

function resizeCanvas() {
  var ratio = Math.max(window.devicePixelRatio || 1, 1);

  // crea un bucle para aplicar los cambios a todos los canvas del array
  for (let x = 0; x < canvas.length; x++) { 
    // This part causes the canvas to be cleared
    canvas[x].width = (canvas[x].offsetWidth * ratio) / 2.5;
    canvas[x].height = (canvas[x].offsetHeight * ratio) / 3;
    canvas[x].getContext('2d').scale((ratio, ratio) / 2);
  }

  signaturePad.clear();
}

window.onresize = resizeCanvas;
resizeCanvas();
```

Como lo que devuelve `querySelectorAll`  es una lista de elementos al momento de ejecutar la instrucción, deberás mover la línea:

```
var canvas = document.querySelectorAll('canvas');
```

al principio de la función `resizeCanvas` (para que *tome los cambios* si se añaden otros `canvas` más adelante). Alternativamente, podrías usar `var canvas = getElementsByTagName("canvas")` fuera de la función, porque [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) devuelve una lista viva de elementos, es decir, la lista de elementos será los que cumplan el requisito en cada momento.

Comment: Si él dice que quiere alcanzar todos los `canvas` que haya en el DOM, no entiendo por qué sugieres que pase por `wrapper`.

Comment: @A.Cedano ¡Buen ojo! Me basé en el código de la pregunta y se me pasó eso por completo. Ya lo he actualizado. Gracias.